# Can I bring carved antler items into the US?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

I hope to purchase small carved reindeer antler weaving tools (heddles, shuttles) in Latvia.  Will I be able to bring those back to the US?  I will be in Russia and Europe between Latvia and the US.  Will I encounter customs issues in Russia or the EU?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18221/can-i-bring-a-small-decorative-deer-skull-from-germany-to-the-us

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know [reindeer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reindeer#Current_status) are not a species listed as endangered and protected under the Convention on International Trade in Endangered Species ([CITES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CITES)) and in that regard you should not have any problems when traveling with some personal horn souvenirs made from reindeer antlers.